# where does the term half in the formula of electrostatic potential energy comes from?(system of point charges)

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, gauss-law, coulombs-law

**Electrostatic potential energy stored in a system of point charges**   (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#Electrostatic_potential_energy_stored_in_a_system_of_point_charges))

The electrostatic potential energy $U_E$ stored in a system of N charges q1, q2, ..., qN at positions r1, r2, ..., rN respectively, is:

$U_\mathrm{E} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N q_i \Phi(\mathbf{r}_i) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N q_i \sum_{j=1}^{N(j\ne i)} k_e \frac{q_j}{r_{ij}}$

where does the term $1\over2$ comes from?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really a matter of combinations. Potential energy is a feature of a system, so between two particles there is one potential energy. The summation however, will cadd the potential energy between two particles twice (e.g., $q_1\phi(\mathbf{r}_2)$ and $q_2\phi(\mathbf{r}_1)$). Hence, the one half term has to be introduced so that the potential energy of each pairing is not added twice.

Comment: Your very welcome. If you found my answer useful you can upvote my answer and press the check, thereby making my answer the official answer, @yurihbss

Comment: I needed to wait 4 minutes :P and I can't upvote yet